# Is there a way with SendEmail that you have a custom text and under that a command output?

Tags: command, sendmail

I am trying to use SendEmail. What I want is that I get an e-mail with the output of a `ls` command but above that output I want a custom text with some explanation. If I try `-u` it overrides my `ls` command output.

The command I use:

```
ls home/ec2-user/client_certs/ | grep '.ovpn' | sendemail -o tls=yes -f Emailthatsendmail@company -t Myemail@company -s smtp.office365.com:587 -xu Emailthatsend@company -xp passwordemailthatsend -u "[Encrypted] Access to VPN Service" -m Users who have access to the VPN service, if something is wrong contact EMAILofCompany
```

For Privacy, I changed the e-mail and passwords.

The result: I get an encrypted mail with the correct subject and body is: Users who have access to the vpn service, if something is wrong contact EMAILofCompany

The `ls` command is nowhere to be found, but if I don't use

`-m Users who have access to the VPN service, if something is wrong contact EMAILofCompany`

I get a mail where I can see the output of the command, but not the custom message because i removed that.

I am using Amazon Linux 2 AMI

SendEmail version: sendemail-1.56

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include the exact command-line you used, the result you get, and an example of what the result should look like, so that contributors can point you in the right direction. Also, please include information on what OS flavor and version and sendmail version you are using.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
The ls command lists directory contents of files and directories. I use the command SendEmail and all the commands work correctly, that's not the problem. The problem is that I can't get the output of the ls command and a custom message together, if I only want one of them in the body it will work, but I want them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your custom message into a file, for example: `/some/path/custom-message.txt`

Then:

```
(cat /some/path/custom-message.txt; ls -d home/ec2-user/client_certs/*?ovpn*) | sendemail -o tls=yes -f Emailthatsendmail@company -t Myemail@company -s smtp.office365.com:587 -xu Emailthatsend@company -xp passwordemailthatsend -u "[Encrypted] Access to VPN Service"
```

Rationale:

With the `-m` option, `sendemail` takes the message from the option argument and ignores the piped standard input completely. You don't want that, so don't use the `-m` option. Instead, by adding parentheses, the outputs of all the commands/pipelines within the parentheses go into `sendemail`'s standard input in the specified order.

Comment: @roaima I tried to apply minimal modifications to the OP's original pipeline, to make it easier to understand the necessary changes, but fair enough - I also have some antipatterns as pet peeves.

Comment: @roaima Looks like you picked it from between the lines just fine :-)

Comment: @roaima thanks alot for your answer, this helped me alot. Is there also a way that i dont see the path from the ls command? example: that I can only see the .ovpn files as output and not /home/ec2-user/client_certs/example.ovpn

Comment: @roaima Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but now there are no enters and everything is next to eachother and I still see the full path

Comment: I've reverted my edit because I don't understand what you want. Does `ls -d home/ec2-user/client_certs/*?ovpn*` give your expected output?

Comment: @roaima Ow I am sorry, I don't get the expected output with that command. What I want is that I don't see the path for (example: user/client_certs/example.ovpn) but what I want is that I only see example.ovpn. For example with `grep` I can get an output that I can only see example.ovpn and not the whole path, but I don't know how to implement that in this command.

Comment: @Danny that's not what you show in your question though. Your `ls /wherever | grep '.ovpn'` will match the full paths shown by `ls` whenever there's `ovpn` in the name. That's what we've repeated here

Comment: @roaima Yes you are right, that was not in my question. I thought if there maybe was a way to make it look a little nicer I could also use that, but if there isn't then this is also good. If I do only this command `ls home/ec2-user/client_certs/ | grep '.ovpn' ` I get as output only the .ovpn files and no paths

Comment: Replace `ls ... | grep ...` with `find /etc/*?ovpn* -maxdepth 0 -printf "%f\n"`. Although I don't think you meant `grep .ovpn` in the first place, so use `find /etc/*ovpn -maxdepth 0 -printf "%f\n"` instead.

Comment: Thanks, find /etc/*ovpn -maxdepth 0 -printf "%f\n" works. But how do I add this in your answer above with sendmail and the custom message?

Comment: Oh, I found it thanks, alot for your help